# Continuous color scale and nice range with pyplor LogLocator

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get a continuous color scale in matplotlib for a log plot. But I also want to preserve the nice tick structure and upper and lower limits in the colorbar.

I can only figure out how to do one or the other.
Here the code that generates the two versions

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1,200, 50)
y = np.linspace(1,300, 50)
z = np.outer(y, x)

bounds = [np.amin(z), np.amax(z)]
bounds = np.log10(bounds)
bounds[0] = np.floor(bounds[0])
bounds[1] = np.ceil(bounds[1])
bounds = np.power(10, bounds)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
tickLocator = ticker.LogLocator()
CS = ax.contourf(x, y, z, locator=tickLocator)
ax.set_title("Not enough color bar levels")
cbar = plt.colorbar(CS)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
tickLocator = ticker.LogLocator(subs=range(1, 10))
CS = ax.contourf(x, y, z, locator=tickLocator)
ax.set_title("Labels missing and not enough range in color bar")
cbar = plt.colorbar(CS)
print("Boundary values")
print(bounds)
print("Tick values")
print(cbar.get_ticks())
plt.show()
```

With the first version I get nice end points for the ticks, but the levels are very coarse.

[image: 1]

With the second version most of the tick labels are missing and the highest tick is smaller than the biggest value in the array.

[image: 2]

Comment: This looks like a very tricky problem.  Three parties are fighting: `contourf` wants its levels evenly spaced and at "nice" positions (probably getting confused by the log scale). LogLocator that doesn't want "too many" major ticks (trying to avoid overlapping labels). And finally LogFormatter that only wants to write a label when the major ticks fall on integer powers of the base.  You might want to rise an issue in matplotlib's github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that works for me by using pcolormesh instead of contourf.
Here the code and output for anyone with a similar problem

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1,200, 200)
y = np.linspace(1,300, 200)
z = np.outer(y, x)

bounds = [np.amin(z), np.amax(z)]
bounds = np.log10(bounds)
bounds[0] = np.floor(bounds[0])
bounds[1] = np.ceil(bounds[1])
bounds = np.power(10, bounds)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, norm=colors.LogNorm(*bounds), shading="auto")
cbar = plt.colorbar(CS, ax=ax)
print("Boundary values")
print(bounds)
print("Tick values")
print(cbar.get_ticks())
plt.show()
```

[image: 1]